# Remove two items at once using removeChild() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove two elements from list (last-child and before-last-child) at once. I'm using jquery with removeChild() but still can't remove two items at once.

**Explanation:**
I have X dots. When you click on (X-1) dot it will make that dot **(X-1) AND x** will be removed from list. Otherwise if you click only on last (X) dot it will make that only one dot will be removed.

**My JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var dots = 12;
var child = document.getElementById("stack");

$('.dot').click(function(){     

    $(this).data('clicked', true);

    if($('.dot:eq(-1)').data('clicked')){
        child.removeChild(this);
        dots -= 1;
    }

if($('.dot:eq(-2)').data('clicked') && $('.dot:eq(-1)').data('clicked'))
        child.removeChild(this);
        dots -= 2;
    }   

    if(dots == 0) {
        alert("End");
    }
});     

});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="board">
    <ul id="stack">
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>
        <li class="dot"></li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.dot {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bc0000;
border-radius: 35px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 15px;
trasition: background 0.2s ease 0s;
}

#stack {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I will be very appreciate if someone could help me.

Cheers

Comment: "*I will be very [appreciative] if someone could help me.*" - can you better, more clearly, explain what it is that you're trying to do? The user clicks on something and then the last two siblings should be removed, or something else? Posting code that doesn't work as the explanation of your problem doesn't work, because the code doesn't work; you need to clearly explain your problem. Then take a moment, and read your question and ask yourself: "with no other information, could I understand this problem?" If not, clarify the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the clarification that you want to remove the clicked `.dot` element and all its subsequent siblings, I'd suggest:

```
// selecting the elements with a class-name of 'dot',
// binding an anonymous 'click' event-handler:
$('.dot').on('click', function() {
  // the clicked element:
  $(this)
    // getting all the later <li> elements with a
    // class-name of 'dot':
    .nextAll('li.dot')
    // adding the initially selected element
    // back to the collection:
    .addBack()
    // fading those elements out, remove()
    // could be used instead, fadeOut() was
    // chosen only to clearly show which elements
    // were being removed:
    .fadeOut();
});
```

```js
$('.dot').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('li.dot').addBack().fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.dot {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bc0000;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease 0s;
}
#stack {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board">
  <ul id="stack">
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, with plain JavaScript, the above can be accomplished with:

```
// a named function to handle the removal,
// the event argument is passed automagically
// from the addEventListener() method:
function removeAllNext (event) {

  // getting the clicked element:
  var clicked = event.target,

      // getting the parent of the
      // clicked element:
      parent = clicked.parentNode;

  // while the clicked element has
  // a next-sibling:
  while (clicked.nextSibling) {

    // we remove that nextSibling from the
    // parent of the clicked element:
    parent.removeChild(clicked.nextSibling);
  }

  // we remove the clicked element:
  parent.removeChild(clicked);
}

// getting the element with an id equal to 'stack':
document.getElementById('stack')
  // binding the removeAllNext() function as the
  // the event-handler for click events:
  .addEventListener('click', removeAllNext);
```

```js
function removeAllNext (event) {
  var clicked = event.target,
      parent = clicked.parentNode;
  while (clicked.nextSibling) {
    parent.removeChild(clicked.nextSibling);
  }
  parent.removeChild(clicked);
}

document.getElementById('stack').addEventListener('click', removeAllNext);
```

```css
.dot {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bc0000;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease 0s;
}
#stack {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board">
  <ul id="stack">
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or, instead:

```
function removeAllNext(event) {
  var clicked = event.target,
    parent = clicked.parentNode,

    // retrieving the child-elements of the parent,
    // using Array.prototype.slice(), with
    // Function.prototype.call(), to convert the
    // NodeList (parent.children) into an array in
    // order to use Array methods:
    children = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children, 0),

    // retrieving the index of the clicked element
    // using Array.prototype.indexOf():
    index = children.indexOf(clicked);

  // if the element wasn't found, Array.prototype.indexOf()
  // returns -1; here we check to ensure that the clicked
  // element was found before acting:
  if (index > -1) {
    // we slice the array to get all elements from
    // the index of the clicked element onwards,
    // and iterate over that Array with 
    /// Array.prototype.forEach():
    children.slice(index).forEach(function(child) {
      // the first argument of the anonymous function
      // (here: 'child') represents the current array-
      // element of the array over which we're iterating:

      // removing the current child from the parent:
      parent.removeChild(child);
    });

  }
}

document.getElementById('stack').addEventListener('click', removeAllNext);
```

```js
function removeAllNext(event) {
  var clicked = event.target,
    parent = clicked.parentNode,
    children = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children, 0),
    index = children.indexOf(clicked);
  
  if (index > -1) {
    children.slice(index).forEach(function(child) {
      parent.removeChild(child);
    });
    
  }
}

document.getElementById('stack').addEventListener('click', removeAllNext);
```

```css
.dot {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bc0000;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease 0s;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#stack {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board">
  <ul id="stack">
    <li class="dot">1</li>
    <li class="dot">2</li>
    <li class="dot">3</li>
    <li class="dot">4</li>
    <li class="dot">5</li>
    <li class="dot">6</li>
    <li class="dot">7</li>
    <li class="dot">8</li>
    <li class="dot">9</li>
    <li class="dot">10</li>
    <li class="dot">11</li>
    <li class="dot"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
  - [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
  - [`while (...) {}` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).
- jQuery:

  - [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
  - [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
  - [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: I would just add some `if(clicked.className.indexOf('dot')<0) return;` at the start of your click handlers but that's a crazy complete answer !

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but there are several obvious mistakes:

1. `child.removeChild(this);` is called 2 times with the same `this`. After the 1st call, this has no effect. You probably meant to remove another `.dot`.
2. `$('.dot:eq(-2), .dot:eq(-1)').data('clicked')` won't "and" the data for you. It will actually return the `clicked` data for the first item picked (`.dot:eq(-2)`). You probably meant to do `$('.dot:eq(-2)').data('clicked') && $('.dot:eq(-1)').data('clicked')`.

Comment: As I said I have list of dots and I want to make that when I click before-last-child dot it will remove itself and last-child dot at once (two in total). I have just started to explore jquery so it is not easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion - I assumed you wanted to delete all until the one clicked. Not sure if that's what you want, but it'll give you an idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var child = document.getElementById("stack");

    $('.dot').click(function(){ 

        var dots = $('.dot').length; 
        var clicked_index = $(this).index()

        for(i=dots;i>=clicked_index;i--){
            $('.dot').eq(i).remove();
            if($('.dot').length == 0) {
            alert("End");
            }
        }

    })
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/jg4gbu43/2/